# Trouble finding file directory using Chrome OS

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm trying to read in a .txt file on chromebook to manipulate the data that is there. My code to source the file is:

```
def readInFile():
    arr_intValues = []
    myFile = open("#MY FILE HERE", "r")
    #you need to change the directory 
    for myLine in myFile:
        arr_intValues.append(int(myLine))
    return arr_intValues

myNewList = readInFile()
print(myNewList)
```

Trouble is, i cannot find out where the source of the file is for this code. If i drop the file into a chrome tab, it reads:

file:///media/fuse/crostini_9549350604ce9beeb7d5a9a66d5bf09733144d34_termina_penguin/RandomNum.txt

Meanwhile the file location that "Get info" returns is:

My files/Linux files/RandomNum.txt

Both of these options fail if I attempt to open it and print it in my code.

How do I find the correct file directory?

I attempted to find the directory of a .txt file on using Chrome OS and have not been successful.

Comment: Why does your question have the "google-chrome-extension" tag?

Comment: @ThomasMueller Beginners are somethings uncertain as to what tags to use.  I removed the extension tag as well as the python-idle tag.  At some reputation level, you will be able to also.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the program on Linux, you'll need to specify the Linux path.

[image]